# Atualização de elemento html

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

**O código abaixo**

```
<div class="input-field">
   <select  id="ramal" multiple  name="ramal[]" >
     <option value="all" id="check-all" name="all" selected >Todas</option>
         <?php 
           if(count($ramais) > 0){
              foreach($ramais as $ramal){
                 formatRamal($ramal);
              }
           }
         ?>
   </select>
   <label>Tipo</label>
</div>



/*esta função encontra-se em outro arquivo*/
function formatRamal($ramal){
        echo "<option  class=\"check-ramal\" value=\"$ramal\">$ramal</option>";
    }
```

**Forma este select com multiplos checkbox, que por padrão fica assim:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A minha dificuldade é atualizar a `<option value="all" id="check-all" selected >Todas</option>` para que apareça desmarcada quando qualquer outro valor for selecionado.

A desmarcação até que é feita, porém não atualiza na tela o que foi feito com o código a seguir.

```
$('#ramal').change(function() {

         if($('.check-ramal').is(":checked")){
            alert("um ramal espcifico foi selecionado");
            $('#check-all').removeAttr("selected");
            $('#check-all').update();
         }

      });
```

**PS* não consigo comentar as respostas, por isso edito aqui para dizer que as respostas abaixo não mostraram a 
`<option value="all" id="check-all" name="all" selected >Todas</option>` desmarcada.**

Mas, funciona na primeira vez que a página é carregada se colocar apenas assim:

```
<script>$('#check-all').removeAttr("selected"); </script>
```

Mas, preciso que a seleção seja removida apenas quando  quando eu selecionar outros valores da do select  e que por padrão fique selecionado se nenhum outro valor for marcado.

Comment: Olá Ramos! Tens já algumas respostas. Para a próxima vez coloca o HTML na pergunta. Assim como está obrigas-nos a escrever à mão e perdemos mais tempo para te poder ajudar. Quando leres este comentário vou apagá-lo. Até breve!

Answer (score 0):

E se você tentar assim:

```js
$('#ramal').change(function() {
    var ramal = $('.check-ramal'),
        tudo = $('#check-all');
    if(ramal.is(':selected')){
        tudo.prop("selected", false);
        //console.log($('#ramal').val());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Podes fazer assim:

```
$('#ramal').change(function() {
    var todas = this.querySelector('#check-all');
    var todasAtivo = this.querySelectorAll('option:checked').length == 1 && todas.selected;
    if (!todasAtivo) todas.selected = false;
});
```

Esse código verifica se só há uma opção escolhida e se essa opção é a `#check-all`. Caso essa permissa não seja válida de-seleciona o `#check-all`.

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1t7np93g/